# How to store barcode into sql server on c# asp.net MVC through IDAutomation_Code39FreeFont?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can successfully generate the barcode but having problem in storing barcode to sql server.

[Success Generate Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR02v.png)

This is my controller.
[GenerateBarCode.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lBcz.png)

```
using OnBarcode.Barcode.BarcodeScanner;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace fyp2_test1.Areas.BarCode.Controllers
{
    public class GenerateBarCodeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: BarCode/GenerateBarCode
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string barcode)
        {
            //var barcode = bar.ToString();
            //System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image barcodeImg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 80))
                {
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                    {
                        Font ofont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
                        PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                        SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                        SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                        graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                        graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", ofont, blackBrush, point);
                    }

                    bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ViewBag.BarcodeImage = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

This is my view.
[Index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95OtJ.png)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_sidePanelPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>Generate Bar Code</h2>
<br />
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "GenerateBarCode", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label><b>Enter Code :</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="textcode" name="barcode" class="form-control col-2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnGenerate" value="Generate" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <hr />

    if (ViewBag.BarcodeImage != null)
    {
        <img src="@ViewBag.BarcodeImage" alt="" />
    }
}
```

This is my overall table.
[myDB.edmx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPlz8.png)

The purpose of barcode scanning system is to store product details and can be retrieve when needed.

Comment: Could you copy/paste your code in your post, it would be easier for everyone

Comment: The bytes that are in the memory stream.  After retrieving you can create the bitmap and graphics from the bytes.  With SQL Server you can use binary to store the data.

Comment: Convert your image to byte array and store it to sql server.

Comment: Currently I have one  product table.Do I need to create one more table for barcode or just add column in product table to store barcode image.